# How to subclass QMessageBox and run operation before closing

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, subclass, qmessagebox

I would like to launch a process within a QMessageBox subclass before it returns via the AcceptRole. It's not clear to me why the following does not work:

```
class Question(QtGui.QMessageBox):

    def __init__(self, text):
        QtGui.QMessageBox.__init__(self, QtGui.QMessageBox.Question, 
           "title", text, buttons=QtGui.QMessageBox.Ok | QtGui.QMessageBox.Cancel)
        self.text = text

    def accept(self):

        # run opertation
        print self.text

        QtGui.QMessageBox.accept(self)

dial = Question("text")
dial.exec_()
```

Since the buttonRole for QMessageBox.Ok is AcceptRole, I would expect `accept()` to be called. Is this not the case?

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: accept() is a slot, it is not called automatically, you have to call it so it will never be called automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea. You just need to reimplement the virtual [done()](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qdialog.html#done) slot, rather than the virtual `accept()` slot:

```
class Question(QtGui.QMessageBox):
    def __init__(self, text):
        QtGui.QMessageBox.__init__(
            self, QtGui.QMessageBox.Question, "title", text,
            buttons=QtGui.QMessageBox.Ok | QtGui.QMessageBox.Cancel)
        self.text = text

    def done(self, result):
        print self.text
        QtGui.QMessageBox.done(self, result)
```

The `result` will be [StandardButton](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qmessagebox.html#StandardButton-enum) value of the button that was clicked (i.e. `QMessageBox.Ok` or `QMessageBox.Cancel`, in the above example).